# Modify a part of the item in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So, I have a list of items like,

```
mylist = ['apple', '"banana"', 'orange']
```

I want to remove double quotes from the item **banana** in mylist. The resulting list should look like this,

```
myresultlist = ['apple' , 'banana', 'orange']
```

I have tried function i.replace('"', "") but no luck. Is it possible?

Comment: What is `i` in `i.replace('"', "")`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i is an item.

Comment: Just realized, I was using replace() in the wrong place in my code.  lel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `str.replace` and list-comprehension:

```py
mylist = ["apple", '"banana"', "orange"]

mylist = [v.replace('"', "") for v in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

Prints:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's more Pythonic than my answer.

Comment: @DanCurry I liked the way you said "Pythonic". It's my first time hearing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['apple', '"banana"', 'orange']

newlist = []

for item in mylist:
    newlist.append(item.strip('"'))

print(newlist)
```